# Will MariaDB treat ut8/utf8mb3 and utf8mb4 collations as compatible?

Tags: index, mariadb, collation, character-set, utf-8

## Background on relevant character sets

MySQL and MariaDB support the [deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html) `utf8mb3` character set and collations. (`utf8` is currently an alias for `utf8mb3`.) This supports all Unicode code points on the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) and stores on-disk using up to 3 bytes.

The more inclusive `utf8mb4` character set supports all Unicode code points (including BMP) using up to 4 bytes on-disk. (`utf8` will alias to `utf8mb4` in the future.) Everything storable with `utf8mb3` is stored the same way (bit-for-bit) in `utf8mb4`. Some things storable with `utf8mb4` are not storable with `utf8mb3`.

## Our tables

We have an index definition using the new character set:

```sql
user_email VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utfmb4 UNIQUE
```

and somewhere else have one using the deprecated version

```sql
email_in_another_table VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 UNIQUE
```

## The question

Will a query using the two indices avoid reading row data (which is slower than indices)?

```sql
SELECT user_email
  FROM a
 UNION -- this is an intersection
SELECT email_in_another_table
  FROM b
```

Comment: Hi there. Have you tried it? This seems like it would be fairly easy to test. Are you able to execute such a query and view the execution plan / do an "explain"? With `utf8mb4` being newer, it might use collation rules from a newer version of Unicode, which wouldn't be compatible with older rules.

Comment: There is something wrong on the question. You say "`UNION -- this is an intersection`", that is just a union that will not print duplicate rows.You can emulate an intersection with an inner join, is that what your really want to ask, if `JOIN ... ON user_email = email_in_another_table` will efficiently use the index?

Comment: My impression is that it treats utf8mb3 and utf8mb4 as different character sets, hence one must be converted to the other before considering comparing.  So, not efficient.